# control ac motor with SCR

Tags: motor, power-electronics, thyristor, scr, ac-motor

I want to repair the circuit of a Mixer that used the TS820 thyristor.
The other components were healthy except the thyristor so I replaced the TS820 with the BT151 but the circuit did not work.
Now I have two questions

1. Can I start the circuit with a BT151 thyristor by changing the resistors or capacitors in the circuit?
2. Can I use MCR100 or C106 thyristors because I can not find the TS820 thyristor?
   [image]

Comment: You need to carefully compare all of the device the specifications. Changing component values may be necessary, but I think that only the gate requirements would be involved. I am pretty sure that the motor is a universal motor. If that is true, that would be the proper motor tag.

Comment: Please rotate your schematic.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I start the circuit with a BT151 thyristor by changing the
> resistors or capacitors in the circuit?

Possibly, but it could be difficult. The [BT151](https://www.tme.eu/Document/a3f2a732350872eddd8f8a3aa9bbd52d/BT151-500C.pdf) has a maximum Gate trigger current requirement of 15 mA, while the [TS820](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ts820.pdf) only needs 0.2 mA. So to get sufficient trigger current you might have to reduce all resistor values (including the pots) by 75 times, as well as increasing C1 by 75 times. With 75 times higher power dissipation the resistors may need higher wattage ratings, which could be particularly troublesome for the pots.

Replacing the SCR with a sensitive Gate type would be much simpler and easier.

> Can I use MCR100 or C106 thyristors because I can not find the TS820
> thyristor?

Probably. The [C106](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_c106_d_datasheet.pdf.pdf) has similar Gate specs to the TS820, so it has a good chance of working.